# Triple Integrals(change in order of integration)

Tags: calculus

I want to double check to make sure I am doing this problem right.

$12xz \ e^{y^2z} dydxdz$ where  $y$ is from $x^2$ to $1$ and both $x$ and $z$ are from $0$ to $1$.

I changed the order of integration to $dxdydz$ and left $z$ unchanged.

so I got $x$ from $0$ to $sqrt(y)$ and both $y$ and $z$ from $0$ to $1$.

After integrating I got $3e-6$

help is very very much appreciated

Comment: the problem is set up correctly now

Comment: sorry about that

Comment: do you know get a more accurate answer now??

Answer (score 1):

Your swapping of the order and changing of the limits of integration is fine, however I got $\frac32$ for the final answer.

Edit: After seeing your edit to the integrand I now get the same answer as you.

Comment: the e is being raise to (y^2) and multiplied by z which is also raised by e

Comment: great thanks for checking it out